# How can I get a UserPrincipal for a user in a different domain?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

The following code works great for users in my domain (e.g., "TESTER" instead of "DEVELOPER"), but I can't figure out how to search higher than the current domain. I tried variation combinations of searches with the PrincipalSearcher class, but I'm not sure how to pass in a search by email address or username to look for other domains within my organization even though they're all in a single forest.

```
var name = "DEVELOPER\\JULIANI99";
var p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), name);
```

Comment: try passing variant of principal context object. new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"domain name here"). I have not tried just a suggestion.

Comment: This does work when I know the domain. Thanks! I would still like to give users more options similar to the user fields in SharePoint, but this will do temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

`FindByIdentity` doesn't work well for searching a forest.

I tried something like this:

```
var d = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com:3268", "DC=com");
var p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(d, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
```

But I keep getting an error saying a referral was returned. It might be different for you. The "3268" port tells it to use the global catalog (forest-wide search). The root (which I have as "DC=com") has to be the common across all the domains in your forest. So if all your domains are sub-domains of "domain.com", then you could put "DC=domain,DC=com". But if you have "domain.com" and "otherdomain.com" part of the same AD forest, then that wouldn't work.

`FindByIdentity` also won't work for searching by email address, so you may just be better off using [PrincipalSearcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373837/how-to-search-global-catalog-whole-forest-using-principalcontext).

If you get the same referral error I got, you can tell it to follow the referral:

```
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(User);
((DirectorySearcher) srch.GetUnderlyingSearcher()).ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
```

Comment: Yes, I got the same error about a referral being returned when I tried that approach earlier. 
I will try this method and let you know.

Comment: How are you using this to get around the referral issue? I receive that error when setting User.EmailAddress or even when passing the User object into the PrincipalSearcher constructor before setting anything on the User object.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I get that too. Looks like you're better off just using `DirectorySearcher` directly. `PrincipalSearcher` is just a wrapper for it "to make things easier", but in this case it just makes things impossible.

Comment: Here's a handy link I've referred to often. In the section "Get an Object DistinguishedName: ADO.NET search (ADVANCED)" it shows how to use DirectorySearcher, although you'll have to change the filter used to search by the `mail` attribute. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/18102/howto-almost-everything-in-active-directory-via-c

Comment: There's a much simpler example of searching the global catalog using `DirectorySearcher` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117741/using-directorysearcher-in-global-catalog-to-find-domain-username